# How to make two different list of strings same?

Tags: python, string, list, set

I have two random lists of strings. The length of two lists won't be necessarily equal all the time. There is no repetition of the elements within a list.

```
list1=['A', 'A-B', 'B', 'C']
list2=['A', 'A-B', 'B', 'D']
```

I want to compare the two lists, and the final output should be two lists with all common elements.

Expected output:

```
list1_final=['A', 'A-B', 'B', 'C','D']
list2_final=['A', 'A-B', 'B','C', 'D']
```

How can I achieve this with a minimum number of lines of code?

Comment: *Sets* would be ideal to solve this…!? Since you've already tagged it [tag:set], any reason you're not using them?

Comment: "all common elements"—You're describing an intersection, but from your expected output, you seem to be asking for a union. Please decide which you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the set python module. Just using `set1.intersection(set2)` you can have the common elements between set1 and set2. Or using `set1.union(set2)` for the union set.

Comment: Note that OPs desired result shows they don't actually want an *intersection*, they want a *union*.

Comment: @deceze I extended the answer

Answer (score -2):

Youve requested 2 lists with all common elements:

```
list1=['A', 'A-B', 'B', 'C']
list2=['A', 'A-B', 'B', 'D']

list1_final=[]
list2_final=[]

for item in list1:
    if item in list2:
        list1_final.append(item)
        list2_final.append(item)
```

returns

list 1 = ['A', 'A-B', 'B']
list 2 = ['A', 'A-B', 'B']

Now your output doesnt match the question asked, do you want all items in both lists? not just the common ones?

Comment: all the items in both list